# Why is this overridden method being called twice?

Tags: apex, debugging

I have three Apex classes. `ObjectController` is abstract and has an abstract method, `table`. `PeopleController` and `LoanBorrowerController` both extend `ObjectController` and each override `table`, the first returning `People__c`, the second `LoanBorrower__c`.

I've written a test on `PeopleController` that is failing. So I turn on the replay debugger, run the test again, download the log, and launch the replay debugger on the log file with a breakpoint within `ObjectController` that's causing the mystery. It's a function that, given a set of Ids, the name of a search field (`idField`), and the name of a return field, returns the records in the return field in the current table where the search field has those Ids.

```
public List<SObject> getByIds(Set<Id> ids, String idField, String returnField) {
  ->String table = this.table();
    String query = String.format(
        'SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} IN :ids',
        new List<Object>{ returnField, table, idField }
    );
    List<SObject> result = Database.query(query);
    return result;
}
```

Originally, there was no `table` variable in the method, but the call to `this.table()` was a direct parameter to `String.format`. The arrow indicates my breakpoint.

For reference, here's `LoanBorrowerController.table()`:

```
public override String table() {
    return 'LoanBorrower__c';
}
```

And `PeopleController.table()`:

```
public override String table() {
    return 'People__c';
}
```

When I run the debugger, the first time it gets to the breakpoint, this is what the call stack looks like:

[image]

So an instance of `LoanBorrowerController` is calling the above method. But here's what happens when I start stepping into the code (each step below is one click of "Step into"):

1. The definition of `LoanBorrowerController.table()` is highlighted.
2. The return statement of `LoanBorrowerController.table()` is highlighted.
3. Control is brought back to `ObjectController.getByIds()` and the breakpoint line is still highlighted.
4. The definition of `PeopleController.table()` is now highlighted!?!
5. The return statement of `PeopleController.table()` is now highlighted.
6. Execution stops.

As far as I can tell, the state of the variables at the breakpoint is correct. `ids` has a set of a single Id (correct for the test), `idField` has `'Loan__c'`, and `returnField` has `'People__c'`. At this point, the query I want is in fact `SELECT People__c FROM LoanBorrower__c WHERE Loan__c IN ('a0655000005thYOAAY')`

So what is going on here? Why is the code calling the `table()` method twice, first as an instance of `LoanBorrowerController` and then as an instance of `PeopleController`? And why does the execution completely *halt* after the 5th "Step In"?

Comment: You have two unit tests, right? It sounds like the logs are truncated or something, or perhaps the replay debugger got confused. I've seen this happen in certain scenarios. I'm not sure why it happens, though.

Comment: I'm only running a single unit test here. I'm running it by clicking the "Run Test" button that appears in VS Code below my @IsTest decorator. But I don't think the log is being truncated. I looked at it and it's show events past this particular failure, including, for example, the assertion failure in the test.

Comment: What do you see if you add a `System.debug` before the return in the two overrides of `table()`?

Comment: (My suspicion is that it isn't being called twice but rather this is simply an artefact in the log.)

Comment: It does get called twice during the test. The first time it's collecting `People__c` fields from `LoanBorrower__c` records. The second time it's collecting all the fields in `People__c` records (the reason I got the `People__c` field in the first place). I do get the hypothesis that there something in the log causing the problem I'm seeing, but I don't see _how_ it's happening. The log file is 5,000 lines long, and gives the limit usage stats.

Comment: Are you accidentally initializing multiple instances of your controllers? Did you try adding `System.debug` in various points of the code flow to help with showing key flow aspects (including construction)?